# Why do people sometimes separate Datasource in other file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datasource, uitableview

I have read that sometimes people separate the datasource of an `UITableView` in a new file, I can not understand why people do that if they can do the same in the `ViewController`.

Could someone explain me this?

Thank you

Comment: Modularity and reuse.

Comment: Sometimes the class get's large enough handling view based things that separating out the data helps keep it readable and maintainable. Sometimes you have sophisticated data tools elsewhere in your app that coordinate intricate work. There are many valid reasons why and when you'd separate these duties, and debating their merits in your specific situation is exactly the right kind of thing to wrestle with.

Comment: Modularity is like, separate all the code in pieces, I mean, to have all the code well organised, isn't it? But for reuse.. You can handle reusability in the `ViewController` too, can't you?

Comment: I guess, I've never had to "wrestle" with this kind of things. I mean, very big problems of reusability.

Comment: Reuse, as in reusable by another class.